# Using default JsonDeserializer inside custom JsonDeserializer in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I'm trying to build custom deserializers for the responses I get from [OMDb API](http://www.omdbapi.com/).

Here's the data class for `Movie`:

```kotlin
data class Movie(
    val title: String?,
    val year: String?,
    val imdbID: String?,
    val type: String?,
    val poster: String?,
    val mpaRating: String?,
    val runtime: String?,
    val genres: String?,
    val director: String?,
    val writers: List<String>?,
    val actors: List<String>?,
    val plot: String?,
    val awards: String?,
    val boxOfficeEarnings: String?,
    val ratings: List<Rating>,
    val response: Boolean?
)
```

And for `Rating`:

```kotlin
data class Rating(
    @SerializedName("Source")
    val source: String,
    @SerializedName("Value")
    val value: String
)
```

This is the custom `JsonDeserializer` so far:

```kotlin
class MovieDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Movie>
{
    override fun deserialize(
        json: JsonElement?,
        typeOfT: Type?,
        context: JsonDeserializationContext?
    ): Movie
    {
        val movieJsonObject = json?.asJsonObject
        return Movie(
            movieJsonObject?.get("Title")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Year")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("imdbID")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Type")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Poster")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Rated")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Runtime")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Genre")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Director")?.asString,
            separateStringByComma(movieJsonObject?.get("Writer")?.asString),
            separateStringByComma(movieJsonObject?.get("Actors")?.asString),
            movieJsonObject?.get("Plot")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Awards")?.asString,
            movieJsonObject?.get("BoxOffice")?.asString,
            // this is where I need help,
            movieJsonObject?.get("Response")?.asBoolean
        )
    }

    fun separateStringByComma(stringToSeparate: String?): List<String>?
    {
        return stringToSeparate?.split(", ")
    }
}
```

How can I convert that JsonElement directly to `List<Rating>` without some json string manipulation?

By the way, I'm using Retrofit with Gson:

```kotlin
val gsonMovieDeserializer = GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(Movie::class.java, MovieDeserializer())
            .create()
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.omdbapi.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonMovieDeserializer))
            .build()
        val omdbApi = retrofit.create(OmdbApi::class.java)
        val movie = omdbApi.getMovie(movieImdbId.value.toString())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to point the usage of nullables there: instead of checking wheter `movieJsonObject` is null or not for every call inside `deserialize()`, you should change the function parameters not to be null and then check only once, right at the beggining, if `json` is a `JsonObject`, just skipping everything if it's not. That way, we have a solid base to extract the data. Also, for the `Movie` data class, check the API documentation for which fields are optional and only set those to nulalble (I'm pretty sure at least the title and ID there are always present, so it's way more useful to have them as non-nullable).

Now, for the question itself, you should probably be able to deserialize that list using `context.deserialize<List<Rating>>(movieJsonObject.get("Ratings"), List::class.java)`, which, in Kotlin, will return a type-safe `List<Rating>` (but, again, make sure that's not an optional field in the API and, if it is, make it nullable).

Comment: This seems to work, thanks! Also, thanks for the nullable advice as well.
Now, what if I need to use another custom deserializer instead of this default one? Do I just use  `RatingDeserializer().deserialize(movieJsonObject.get("Ratings"), List::class.java, context)`

Comment: That may be a way to do so, but you can simply make a new class extending `JsonDeserializer` for the appropriate type and register it in the `GsonBuilder` and Gson will do everything for you. I don't recommend instantiating a deserializer as that's done by Gson itself, which will reuse it every time its needed. Also, if you really need to go full manual mode, then just make a function inside the `MovieDeserializer` itself and call it from `deserialize()` when needed, as it may be more concise and a good way of reusing the code.